# Preffered way to define readonly property with getter function

Tags: delphi

What would be the preferred method to define a read only property with a Getter function:

```
TMyClass = class(TObject) 
private
 function GetValue: integer
public
 property Value: integer read GetValue;
end;
```

or

```
TMyClass = class(TObject) 
public
 function Value: integer;
end;
```

[Edit]I know it is also a matter of taste so I'll rephrase the question into:
What are the pro's and con's of both methods?

Comment: The first one, because the latter is not a property.

Comment: The second form is not actually a property - otherwise it's a matter of taste, really.

Comment: This is quite clearly opinion based. Different people will have different preferences.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. The second option does not define a property at all, so they're totally different things., (Property declarations start with `property ...`, after all, and not `function`.)

Answer (score 1):

The first one is the preferred way to do it. 
As you want to read a value by its name it's the common way to do it by a property. A `function` is usually named by an instruction like `GetValue` or `ExtractFilePath` etc. Variables and properties are named by the value they store.

Comment: Actually I dispute what you state here. A common convention is to use a noun for function names and a verb for procedure names. So the function name is simply the name of the thing that the function yields.

Comment: Beside a few exceptions like `Length` I see a plenty of functions which are named by the thing they _do_ but not what they yield. At least it feels to me that `GetValue` is a description of what is being _done_ inside. There is almost no noun used as function name in the code I'm working on (most of that code is written by other developers).

Comment: Invariably with a function one writes `x := func()` and good functions don't have side effects. So, name them as nouns so that you know what they return. Name a procedure (with side effects) as a verb.

Comment: OK, obviously we have a different taste. I agree, good functions don't have side effects. But function calls can be expensive and do more than just returning a value that has already been stored (for example a function that returns the result of a complex sql count query). I personally like to see at one glance that a line of code does more than returning a value. I see it when a function is called `CountFemaleUsersInDB` instead of naming it `NumberOfFemaleUsersInDB` which may implies that the number has already been determined. 
But of course this is a matter of taste.

Comment: This is why this question should be closed as primarily opinion based. We all have our own opinions, and I would not want to claim that mine are any better than yours.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the biggest practical difference is if you have any code that uses RTTI to inspect properties (anything using streaming, for instance) then Option 1 will work with this, option 2 won't. Additionally, if this is in a class with an inheritance structure you won't be able to alter the visibility as easily with option 2.

Option 2 on the other hand is more concise and may be all you need if it's a simple program.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are actually going to do with that function; for example, if you want it to hook into live bindings (Prototype Bind Source for instance) you will need to declare the property